# How to use C# to add a column for a table of sql server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How to use C# to add a column for a table of sql server?

For example, I want to execute the following sql in C# code:

```
alter table [Product] add 
[ProductId] int default 0 NOT NULL
```

Comment: The question and answer are too obvious. Plus one can run such script (add column to a table) just once. Yes, DDL is supported in `SqlClient` namespace.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev: yeah, a case of RTM-itis goin' on...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use a Command:

```
using (DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string")) {
    connection.Open();
    using (DbCommand command = new SqlCommand("alter table [Product] add [ProductId] int default 0 NOT NULL")) {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: DbCommand also implements IDisposable, so I'd suggest putting that in a using block as well.

Comment: Thank you. But the above code missed the:
command.Connection = connection;

Comment: How can you check that query was done correctly?because executeNonQuery return -1

Answer (score 3):

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
// create columns for healed
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE TotalHeals ADD "+Healee+" INT", openCon);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Funny how SqlCommand is different then DBCommand