# Adding column-name dynamically in alter table

Tags: asp.net, sql, alter-table

I am developing a web application and need to use ALTER Table in it.
Here is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD [column-name] [Type] DEFAULT [default-value] NULL/NOT NULL
```

Now i want to change [column-name] dynamically by a text box. How can i do that?
In addition i used @name in AddWithValue, but it doesn't work!
Can any body help me?
Thanks

here is my whole code:

```
SqlConnection sqlconn4 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString);
                   SqlCommand sqlcomm4 = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE aspnet_Membership ADD @column int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL", sqlconn4);

                    sqlcomm4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", TextBox1.Text);
                    sqlconn4.Open();
                    sqlcomm4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlconn4.Close();
```

Comment: you have two questions actually and should ask separately. for addwithvalue not working you should provide source code.

Comment: I add my code to my question.

Comment: and do you wanto to just change your column name or add new columns to table. questions subject is changing but example source code is about adding new columns.

Comment: Ohh my god!! thank you for mentioning that. I was awake whole the night! it is about adding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351651/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-add-a-column-for-a-table-of-sql-server then use alter table add like in linked answer and get a sleep

Comment: Thanks. I wish i could...:)

Comment: But there is one more problem, I want to get the name from a text box! that was my main problem.

Comment: I have edited answer hope it helps. Somehow it didn't work with addwithvalue. so you have to sanitize input before using function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) procedure you can change column name.

```
sp_RENAME 'Table_First.Name', 'NameChange' , 'COLUMN'
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/

```
public void AddNewColumn(string tableName, string columName, string dataType)
    {
        string commandText = String.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD {1} {2} ", tableName,columName,dataType);

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("===="))
        {
            var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible only with dynamic SQL queries:

```
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD ' + @column + ' INT'

Exec (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below thing..

dataTable.Columns["column-name"].ColumnName = "updated column-name";

Comment: How can i add a column to it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, perhaps posting a sample of your code would help. For example, is your column-name variable a static variable? If the variable is not declared static it will be declared with its default value every time the Alter table method is called and the changes made to it by the textbox textChanged event.

On the other hand if your current problem is trying to get the dynamic portion to work are you using the textChanged event of your textbox to alter the column-name variable?

Once again more information would be greatly appreciated.