# Alterations to SQL Server table don't seem to build in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a C# front-end to SQL Server back-end using Visual Studios 2017. When I initially created my table in the database, it was:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHazard_Reports]
(
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Badge] INT NOT NULL,
    [Full Name] VARCHAR NOT NULL
)
```

I have since changed it to

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHazard_Reports]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Badge] INT,
    [Full Name] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

However, when I run my `SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` statement, I'll either get the error that a column does not allow NULL or that a string or binary data will be truncated. Although everything in my project seems to show that my changes to the columns have been made, I get errors as if I never touched it.

I've looked online for a place to put a proper ALTER statement in Visual Studio, but I can't find anything. How can I rebuild my table to reflect the changes I've made?

Here is my C# code in case it is relevant.

```
private void InsertHazardItem(E3_Project.HazardItem currHaz)
{
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        string commandString = "INSERT INTO tblHazard_Reports([ID], [Badge], 
            [Full Name]) VALUES(@ID, @Badge, @Name)";

        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, cnn))
        {
            var parameterID = new SqlParameter("@ID",  System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            var parameterBadge = new SqlParameter("@Badge",  System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            var parameterName = new SqlParameter("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);

            parameterID.Value = currHaz.ID;
            parameterBadge.Value = currHaz.Badge;
            parameterName.Value = currHaz.Name;

            command.Parameters.Add(parameterID);
            command.Parameters.Add(parameterBadge);
            command.Parameters.Add(parameterName);

            cnn.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //The error is always on this line
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the ID should be auto-incrementing, but I have it included here because, again, it doesn't seem that my change to the table has been built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterations to a table must be done in code. In my case, I ended up using C# and ExecuteNonQuery to do so, [as shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351651/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-add-a-column-for-a-table-of-sql-server)

Even new tables must be created with code and executed directly with code. Adding a new table to my database using the Visual Studio tools did not seem to actually show up and be used.

Comment: My experience does not reflect this . . . I am used to altering the database using the SQL Server Management Studio and then rebuilding my front end .NET project sees the changes when using a data connection (LINQ to SQL, but the EF should work the same way).  How are you connecting your C# project to the database?

Comment: For testing purposes, I created a local SQL Project in the same solution as my C# project. Therefore, my database is only on my local machine, and I maintain it using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined the ID column as an IDENTITY column, the database takes care of setting that value when you INSERT a row. Try removing the ID column from your INSERT statement and it should work.

**Unrequested Hint**: You and everyone who ever uses your database will be much happier if you do not include spaces in your column names.  [Full Name] would be better as FullName.

Comment: Alright, I removed reference to ID in my INSERT statement, as well as removing the parameter. I also changed my column names like you suggested haha. Now I get the error message "Invalid column name 'FullName'". Which goes to show, I think, that the table isn't actually updating or that the front-end isn't connecting to the updated table

Comment: @TravisRowe if you are getting an "Invalid column name" error, then you haven't updated your database.  You can use sp_RENAME 'dbo.tblHazard_Reports.[Full Name]' , 'FullName', 'COLUMN' to change the column name.

Comment: do I put that in my C# code, or do I make an SQL Script to run a command to alter my database? Right now, I've made the changes to the column names in the CREATE statement of my table.

Comment: @TravisRowe - generally, you will change the *structure* of your database using scripts and the *data* using C#.  Renaming a column changes the structure of the database, so you should do this in a script.